Keyframes don't change on geometry node driven animation
I made a geometry node animation, and I am new to animation settings on Blender. I looked at some solutions, but I need some support.
I am trying to change a geometry node value that changes this fractal neuron shape. I want to set keyframe, not sure what I should use when I press 'K', I tried locaton, rotation, scale, and setup several different keyframes with the image staying exactly as it was.
What do I need to know to solve this issue? I tried a simple NPC animaiton tutorial, and even a new Blender file and the keyframes work, so using geometry nodes might be why.


Have you tried right-clicking on the Geometry node field that you want to keyframe and selecting "Insert Keyframe" ?

That was the answer, thanks a ton! I felt so stuck seeing all the widgets.

No problem. That applies to almost any setting field in Blender. Glad you're sorted!
